# Avoid hidden element occupying space/not possible to make visibility:true which is initially made display:none in css style

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

```
<style type="text/css">
#second{
 display:none;
}
</style>
```

**On mouse event I want to pass id's of div which is not related to current element from where I am calling the function.**

```
<div id="first">
     ....
     ....
</div>
<div id="second">
     ....
     ....
</div>

<input type="image" src="..." id="notrelated"
 onClick="f('first','second')"
 />
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function f(first,second){
document.getElementById(first).style.display='none';
document.getElementById(second).style.visibility='visible';
}
</script>
```

The above function thus helps in hiding and make the div visible which is based on mouse event on image.

I followed these above steps,after making visibility 'visible' it wont show because I've made div second display none and I tried making the following changes which results in second div occupying space which I don't prefer:

```
<style type="text/css">
#second{
visibility:hidden;
}
</style>
```

Comment: i seriously dont understand your question, what you have in your code itself will work, what else do you want to do ?

Comment: Do you want to pass id of all other divs?

Comment: So which is the criteria for you to know which divs you want to select?

Comment: @undefined here the first div is visible in beginning and second div display is made none, so that somewhere in html script i got image when i click that image i have to toggle the display which is done by function, so is it possible to pass independent id's to function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I got your question, you just want to pass your div ids in the function. So you can easily pass it in any function.

Like

```
<input type="image" src="..." id="notrelated" onClick="Toggle('first','second')" />
```

and your js function will work

```
function Toggle(first,second){
   document.getElementById(first).style.visibility='hidden'
   document.getElementById(second).style.visibility='visible'
}
```

But If you want that only passing these id you want to toggle these, then you should change your function to like

```
function Toggle(first,second){
   var firstDiv = document.getElementById(first);
   var secondDiv = document.getElementById(second);
   firstDiv.style.visibility= firstDiv.style.visibility == 'hidden'?'visible':'hidden';
   secondDiv.style.visibility= firstDiv.style.visibility == 'hidden'?'visible':'hidden';
}
```

You can check this **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/meUuK/)**

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right , you want to pass the ids of other DOM elemnts , this case divs. 
To select other DIVS you will need to add class to those DIVS.

```
<div class = 'someclass1' id ='one'></div>
```

and on your onclick event pass

```
$('.someclass1').attr('id');
```